# Automating translation in Sketch

Tags: sketch-3

I have a really simple question but am really struggling to find a solution for my problem.

I have an Excel file with translations for every item in my Sketch design. I have to find the right item and then change the text that is there to the translated text in my Excel file. Is there a way to set up my design so that I can use my Excel file in a way, that it places the correct text with the corresponding lable in my Sketch design? Something along the lines of using different XML files in Android Studio for multiple language support.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out using [this](https://github.com/preciousforever/data-populator) plugin, you can use json files to populate your artboards.